# auto renewal in app purchases?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, sdk, in-app-purchase

I've been programming in Xcode for a year now, last time i attempted to use in app purchases i gave up after two weeks of getting nothing done. I am ready to try again but so far i have gotten no progress and everything i tried has failed.

I've also tried the simpleSDK tutorial on YouTube and when i pressed the purchase button on my phone nothing happened.

Can someone supply good code that works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use MKStoreKit then

http://blog.mugunthkumar.com/coding/mkstorekit-4-0-supporting-auto-renewable-subscriptions/